# How do you center align in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm used to Microsoft Word when typing a document so I don't know all the shortcut keys on how to do stuff. I just wanna know how to Center Align it would save time than just hitting tab until I reached the center. If possible what are other basic shortcut keys in LibreWriter. I'm still a newbie to Linux, plus it's been awhile since I worked in word, thank you

Comment: `<Ctrl+E>` is shown when you mouse-hover above *Center Horizontally* text button.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + e` will Center align the cursor for you.

You can also use the menu: `Format -> Align`

Or click the "Center Text" button in the formatting toolbar:

[image]